# Azure Synapse Notebook Folders Structure not saved in GitHub

Tags: github, azure-synapse

My Synapse Workspace is configured with GitHub.   The code is organized in folders under "NoteBook".  Example: Under Notebook, Dev1 folder contains notebook1 and notebook2.  Dev2 folder contains notebook3 and notebook4

When Synapse Publishes, the GitHub Repo does not maintain the folder structure.  All 4 files are under "repo_name/notebook/ notebook1, notebook2,notebook3, notebook4

How can do I configure Synapse GitHub to keep the folder structure?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you don't. When you save a notebook (or SQL script, or anything else for that matter), you are actually saving a JSON representation of the asset. The "folders" in Synapse are not actually folders, but rather properties in the JSON:

[image]

This is why file names need to be globally unique, so you can't have two "Notebook1" files in different folders. Again, same for SQL scripts, datasets, pipelines, etc.

Comment: Hi Joel.  Thx for the quick explanation.  My support requirements:  1) I need to create a new Synapse Workspace from this GitHub repo with the latest version or a "labeled/tagged" previous version.    2) Use this GitHub repo and populate a Databricks Workspace.  What are the steps for these 2 requirements.   Thx.

Comment: I don't have any advice for that scenario. I recommend you create a new question that addresses that specifically, maybe someone else has some insights.